# Change the value of the interface with pointer - can not take the address of problem

Tags: go

```
json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &result)
```

After json.Unmarshal, the result is a `map[string]interface{}`

I can manipulate the values of the map direcly with:

```
result["player"].(map[string]interface{})["inventory"].(map[string]interface{})["gold"]=100
```

But this is a long variable name, I want to appoint a pointer to adress of this and manipulate with a shorter name like:

```
gold:=&result["player"].(map[string]interface{})["inventory"].(map[string]interface{})["gold"]
```

Then manipulate only *gold.

Trying to do this, I get the error:

> *cannot take the address of result["player"].(map[string]interface {})["inventory"].(map[string]interface {})["gold"]*

Comment: Map elements are not addressable. If you want to manipulate it this way you should strongly consider defining appropriate `struct` types to match the data.

Comment: `"gold"` here is a number if some sort, so modifying a pointer to that value is not going to modify it in the map. Just assign the map to a temporary variable if you want to reuse it.

Comment: @Adrian, thanks for verifying what I suspected. At first it seems illogical that a value not to have a kind of variable that can be pointered but I think this is because maps are dynamic and memory adress can change. To have a struct was my first idea but the json I try to manipulate is dynamic and map was a better solution. Thank you indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map elements are not addressable; the map implementation is permitted to rearrange the elements in memory as needed, which would invalidate any pointers to those elements. [Per the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> For an operand `x` of type `T`, the address operation `&x` generates a pointer of type `*T` to `x`. The operand must be addressable, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array.

A map element is not among the list of addressable values.

You're better off defining struct(s) to match your data structure if at  all possible; it will vastly simplify all usage of that data in your code. You can use [json-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to frame out the data structure for you, though this should only be used to provide a working starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change or assign a value to `gold` element, take the gold map and assign the value for map key `gold`

```
goldMap := result["player"].(map[string]interface{})["inventory"].(map[string]interface{})
goldMap["gold"] = 100
```

But, Make sure your initial maps are not `nil`. Otherwise the binary will panic. To do that, you need to assign all the maps one by one and check whether `nil or not`